# Is it possible to use FCIS: Fully Convolutional Instance-aware Semantic Segmentation without using CUDA?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I was reading a work on github (https://github.com/chrieke/InstanceSegmentation_Sentinel2) where it requires the use of [FCIS](https://github.com/msracver/FCIS) and mxnet for deep learning, following the tutorial I saw that the installation of CUDA is required an extension of NVIDIA while I have available a video card AMD Radeon HD Series.

I wanted to know if I have trouble proceeding because I don't have nvidia or can I use OpenCL as a better alternative?

I started with running the command sh ./init.sh but it returns:

```
skipping 'bbox.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_linux.py", line 56, in <module>
  CUDA = locate_cuda()
File "setup_linux.py", line 51, in locate_cuda
  for k, v in cudaconfig.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup_linux.py", line 56, in <module>
   CUDA = locate_cuda()
File "setup_linux.py", line 51, in locate_cuda
  for k, v in cudaconfig.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Secondly, running the command demo.py from FCIS says it doesn't find the command even though the path is correct:

```
./FCS/fcis/demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./fcis/demo.py", line 21, in
from utils.image import resize, transform
File "/home/..../..../lib/utils/image.py", line 6, in
from bbox.bbox_transform import clip_boxes
File "/home/..../..../lib/bbox/bbox_transform.py", line 3, in
from bbox import bbox_overlaps_cython
ImportError: cannot import name bbox_overlaps_cython
```

I changed it to from bbox import `bbox_overlaps_cython` to `from bbox.bbox import bbox_overlaps_cython`,and used python 2.7 as suggested but did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`
If you are using Python 3 then replace `iteritems` with `items` only.

I am using the same thing as you are and this FCIS sentinel 2 only will work with Python 2.7 and if you use Python 3 then it will give so many errors.